# Google is dropping indexed pages faster than they are being uploaded

Tags: seo, google, google-search-console, backlinks, penalty

[I have recently opened a bounty regarding unnatural links appearing in my search](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/95435/unnaturally-high-number-of-links-from-domain) console due to no fault of my own. Many asked for the names of the sites, however, I would prefer to keep it quite - simply because it is from a fierce competitor in my niece.

I have linked to the previous questions since the following question may or may not be related to the question I am about to ask.

**My Problem**

Google is dropping indexed pages faster than they are being uploaded...and I upload daily. and check `site:www.example.com` daily

Currently `site:www.example.com` returns less results everyday, it currently returns 20 results with 5 of those results being pages, thus only 15 posts displaying with a `site` search, despite having well over a 100 quality posts, all which shows indexed in search console...

The ironic thing is...when performing `site:www.example.com` on a mobile device ALL my posts gets returned

**My Question**

1. ***How accurate is `site:` search and how much should I read into it?***
2. Anyidea why all pages with `site:` search are displaying on mobile devices but not on desktops?
3. Pasting the url into search bokes or using `""` around text yields no results on desktop?
4. Can all of the above be indication of a penalty? If yes, I dont think I have the time or resources to fight it and would rather abandon the domain...if doing so and 301'ing my top pages with best links will that transfer penalty to new domain?
5. Is this something which should likely be waited out?
6. Any other advice

**SideNote:**

*I am willing to provide my domain name, if allowed by community...Providing it can be used in helping to diagnose the problem, kindly request it from me, should you wish to be kind enough to have a look.*

Many Thanks to all the great contributions.

Comment: Ah ha! From a competitor huh? This answer helps you to understand the site: search directive: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/72610/number-of-indexed-pages-with-site-search-less-than-reported-in-google-webmast/87808#87808 Mobile versus Desktop is simply applying a mobile friendly filter. It may help to provide a domain name. Not against the rules exactly. Just not preferred in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few questions:-

1. Any drop in traffic and ranks?
2. Since when have you started noticing the drop in the number of indexed pages with the site: operator?
3. Any message from Google in the search console?

The `site:` operator is supposed to show the approximate number of pages indexed in Google. However, do note that if your pages have thin content or are deep down in the hierarchy that they do not have enough link equity reaching them, Google will drop them from their index.

Of course, there could be other issues like Panda which is specifically targeted towards sites with low quality content.

If you can PM me or post the link to yoir site, we can check further and advise accordingly.

Comment: 1) Drop in traffic....NO since 95% comes from social media...drop in rankings YES...avg 100 google hits a day now lucky if 10....2) Started noticing  drop with `site:` operator about 3-weeks ago which has gotten progressively worse just found out today my homepage have been dropped....3)No message from google in searchconsole and they are showing all posts as index yet `site:` now only returns 1 page of results...ironicially my least visited posts / pages

Comment: I cant find a way to PM you so I have opened a room and invited you http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/41897/google-indexing?tab=general PLEASE PLEASE join if you have a minute...I am willing to pay for any help

Comment: In the chatroom now

Comment: just popped you a message